# Get-ADUser triggered by Button

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a button on a WinForm. After clicking on the button, a function will be called which should execute Get-ADUser cmdlet.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ctl_frm_aduserlist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
    StartPosition = "CenterScreen" } 
$ctl_btn_generatepreview = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
        Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,30)
        Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
        Text = "Generate Preview" } 
$ctl_frm_aduserlist.Controls.Add($ctl_btn_generatepreview)

$ctl_btn_generatepreview.Add_Click({ GeneratePreview })

function GeneratePreview(){
    Write-Host "GO"
    Get-ADUser -Identity "user123" -Properties Name,SamAccountName | select Name,SamAccountName
    Write-Host "END" }

$ctl_frm_aduserlist.ShowDialog()
```

Only the two "Write-Host" cmdlets will be executed by clicking on the button.

If I only execute the single line Get-ADUser in the ISE console, it works and I get the user object.
Why does Get-ADUser not work when triggered via button?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code of your WinForms Button

Comment: Try to put GeneratePreview()-Function on top after Add-Type lines.

Comment: @LuttiCoelho the code is there..

Comment: @f6a4 I put it there and tried again. Still does not work

Comment: In ISE the default output is to the host console. In the form you're not telling the object "where to go". Pipe the output to "Out-Host" to get your desired result.

Comment: @Scepticalist Thanks, now I can see the result in the ise console. Do you have an idea why $myuser stays empty if I do "$myuser = Get-ADUser -Identity "user123" -Properties Name,SamAccountName | select Name,SamAccountName" via button?

Comment: It;s not empty. The $myuser variable is scoped within the function (form) - add the line $myuser | Out-Host and you'll see it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6 for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't have a full solution as I'm not an expert in WinForms, to feel free to correct/complete this answer.

As far as I know, the command is actually executed. You can check it by stepping though the code or `Write-Host`-ing bits of the object you collected with `Get-ADUser` and it will display the correct info:

```bsh
function GeneratePreview() {
    Get-ADUser -Identity "someone" | Write-Host
}
```

Note that if you replace `Write-Host` by `Write-Output` it does not work anymore.

The thing is, when you make a WinForms application, the standard output isn't the console anymore. I don't know where it is redirected to, but it's not visible by default. You need to either specify that you want to see your data in the console with `write-host`, export it to a file (`Set-Content`, `Export-Csv`, you name it) or display it in a WinForm element:

I added a new TextBox to your form (called $TextBox1 in my example), and changed GeneratePreview like this:

```bsh
function GeneratePreview() {
    $user = Get-ADUser "someone"
    $TextBox1.Text = "$($user.name),$($user.samaccountname)"
}
```